# Get part of the match

Tags: regex

I have the following text format:

```
Phrase:
cat, fish.
Some text.
Phrase:
flat, apple, orange.
Other text.
```

I want to extract only the words after the `Phrase:` up to the next new line:

`cat, fish, flat, apple, orange`

This is the regex I am trying in `Regexr.com`:

`(Phrase:)\n(.*)` but it matches both the `Phrase` and the words.

How to get only the words?

Comment: where have you tried it? Any online tool? or in any programming language? Add more details

Comment: @mtk question is updated.

Comment: have a try with https://regex101.com/ , it will help you design your regex to match the data you have , it does a great job of explaining what the regex does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that do :

```
/Phrase:\n([^\n]*)\n/g
```

By that you will get anything between Phrase:\n(anything)\n

and the group[1] has the anything content

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript regexes (assuming here, since you're using regexr) you cannot. In most regex engines you can use a positive lookbehind to model that:

```
(?<=Phrase:\n).*
```

Which will match only the part *after* "Phrase:". However, in JavaScript you don't have lookbehind. The best you can do is what you already do: Put the part you're interested in in a group and extract that group instead.

Comment: how do I extract a group?

Comment: @CuriousGuy, that depends on your programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to(or can use) use python, then normal split function of string would do the job

```
In [1]: s
Out[1]: 'Phrase:\ncat, fish.\nSome text.\nPhrase:\nflat, apple, orange.\nOther text.'

In [2]: print s
Phrase:
cat, fish.
Some text.
Phrase:
flat, apple, orange.
Other text.



In [3]: s.split('Phrase:\n')
Out[3]: ['', 'cat, fish.\nSome text.\n', 'flat, apple, orange.\nOther text.']

In [4]: l = s.split('Phrase:\n')

In [5]: print l[0] #Yes it's empty


In [6]: print l[1]
cat, fish.
Some text.


In [7]: print l[2]
flat, apple, orange.
Other text.
```

Comment: You can use the regex by joey in the split function also.